# WCF Webservice UserCredentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I want to add the UserCredentials of the Webservice i use into my web.config file of my website.

e.g.:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>             
           <customBinding>                                  
             <binding bindingConfiguration="myBinding"  
               <security enableUnsecuredResponse="true" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" />
               <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
               <httpsTransport />
             </binding>                           
           </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://www.mycompany.com/foo.ashx"  binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBinding" username="123" password="123"  contract="foo.bar" name="foosoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

username="123" password="123"

instead of

```
ws.SomethingServiceClient svc = new ws.SomethingServiceClient();
svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = 123;
svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = 123;
```

Comment: take a look on this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96028/WCF-Service-with-custom-username-password-authenti

Comment: This link will be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725294/set-wcf-clientcredentials-in-app-config